# Using Java Objects To Create a CPLEX Model

Tags: java, cplex

Im looking to build a CPLEX model for team optimisation in fantasy football using CPLEX within Java.

I have a set of Player objects and a player has a name, position, points and salary variable. A team then contains 9 players and I'm looking to maximise the teams points while keeping to a given budget as well as having a player in each of the positions needed (1 QB, 2 RB, 3 WR, 1 TE, 1 Flex and 1 DEF).

How should I go about using the variables in the object to create the constraints in for the CPLEX model?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the provided examples? Normally I would declare the decision variables and construct expressions by iterating over the sets (lists, arrays, disctionaries...) of objects, adding the necessary constraints to a CPLEX model and then getting CPLEX to solve it. What have you tried so far ... you aren't giving us much to work with here...

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick 

`IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex(); 
  
  int count = 0;
  for (Player player: players){
 playerNames[count] = player.name;
 points[count] = player.points;
 wages[count] = player.wage;
 pos[count] = player.pos;
  }
}`

So I have arrays containing all the values needed to be included in my CPLEX model. How do I then add these to my model and add the constraints?

I've played around with the example code provided however cant get anything to work with what i'm trying to do. 

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but what are your 'decisions'? A crucial first step in building these optimisation models is understanding what 'decisions' you want your optimiser to make. Once you know what is your basic model for those decisions, you can start adding constraints on which combinations of decisions are allowed. I am guessing  that you want to know which players to include in your team? If so, then you would probably want an IloNumVar (or similar) for each player, so that would mean that a 1 would mean the player is in the team, while a 0 means they are not included.